# How much time passes during the time skip?

Tags: arcane

There is a bit of a time skip between the events of Act 1 and those of Act 2, during which a number of characters grow up or change careers.

In the "Council Archives" content, there is a list of records related to Vi's time as a prisoner, of which the earliest lists her as "approximately 17" and the latest suggests that she is in her early 20s. Still, that suggests that anywhere between two years (if she was 18 when incarcerated and 20 when released) to eight years (if she was 16 when incarcerated and 24 when released) could have passed. Perhaps even longer, if the last record was some time before Caitlyn released her.

So, how much time passes between Vi and Powder being separated and the events of episode 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 6-7 years, as shown in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/leeloo104/status/1463645074349191169) from one of the writers of *Arcane*.

> Caitlyn and Vi are about the same age in the first act, maybe a year apart? Somewhere in 14-16 age. Powder is 11-12ish. And we think about 6-7 years passed between episodes. This is all approximate since time is a bit different in Runeterra, and a bit open to interpretation.

[image]

This fits with the time range described in the question, on the high end, if Vi was 16 when she went to prison. Of course, "time is different in Runeterra" according to the tweet (blame Ekko, he "broke" it).

Comment: She may not have any idea about her character’s canon details but Ella Prunell (Powder’s voice actress) says something like:
"she’s childish she’s stuck at the age of 9 which is when she was traumatized." (4:30) https://youtu.be/8rRIHwn5LyU

Comment: Judging by the hair growth, [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/everyday-life/hair-growth) says it takes about 6.5 years to grow a one-meter-long hair. But Jinx's hair seemed to be longer than that. So maybe hair growth is faster in the Piltover undercity 

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ - Her hair is longer than most people can even grow. They probably have weird chemical treatments in Zaun.